# Does PCI PIN Security allows keeping the PIN in-memory for a short period of time?

Tags: pci-dss

I've been asked to implement a page where a user can unblock her account by credit card number and PIN validation + some other method (e.g. SMS OTP) in a two-step process.

The flow suggests validating the CC number and PIN first and then do the SMS OTP validation.

In order to prevent abuse of back-end resources and possible PIN blocking at scale, one idea is:

- Have the first page capture the CC number and PIN
- Use only the CC number to find the user
- Send an SMS OTP to her mobile
- If SMS OTP checks, *then* validate CC number and PIN

So, CC number and PIN will be held in memory (HTTP session) from the time the user entered them on the first page until she receives and submits the OTP on the second page (a few minutes, I guess).

Does that violate any PCI rules? Especially the "keep the PIN in memory" part?

[PIN Security Requirements, Version 2.0](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_PIN_Security_Requirements_v2.pdf), reads:

> **Requirement 4**: PINs must not be stored except as part of a store-and-forward transaction, and only for the minimum time necessary. If a
>   transaction is logged, the encrypted PIN block must be masked or deleted from the record before it is logged.

and right below:

> Transactions may be stored and forwarded under certain conditions - [ISO 9564](https://www.iso.org/standard/68669.html)

I checked an older version of ISO 9564-1 but I did not find anything with regards to store and forward. Does anybody have some insight on the conditions under which store and forward is allowed?

Moreover, does keeping the PIN in memory for a short period of time even qualify as "store"?

Comment: Why not only ask for pin after SMS OTP checks? Although would abuse of the SMS back-end not be more expensive than the PIN check? / Could this not better be solved by IP rate limiting?

Comment: There are many ways to solve the issue by changing the flow but let's assume that the UX cannot change.

Comment: My knowledge of the spec is aging but I believe memory only would be fine. You might want to take steps to ensure that memory isn't paged. Another "UX doesn't change" option might be to cache the pin in the client until after successful SMS checks. I would reiterate that I would not do either unless you absolutely have to - and there aren't many legitimate arguments for not changing the UI here. Especially seeing as this should be an edge case user action.

Comment: I don’t think this will be PCI compliant at all. And even if you find a hole it is much too risky. For so called sensitive authentication data I would only use validated pinentry devices and pa-dass authenticated software. Besides which processor would authenticate with PIN anyway? (Your scenario looks more like CVV than PIn)

Comment: @eckes, PINs are supposed to be entered only on "Physically Secure Devices"(this is actually Requirement #1) but it turns out this is a real world requirement (every Bank does it on that specific country) and there is a back-end service that exposes this API to my app. From my personal experience, a mobile-only Bank I use allows you to change the PIN from within the app. This would also violate the requirement.

Comment: @eckes, can you elaborate on "pa-dass"? What is this?

Comment: It’s a typo,). PA-DSS, the payment software validation program of PCI

Comment: Have you been through many audits? Not being snarky, but my experience is auditors are most interested in "audit-able security"... Can -you- secure this in a way that make sense from an audit standpoint (documented/effective/context appropriate)? I only ask because your question is detailed and clearly implies knowledge of the environment. Make this secure, document, and I'll bet you'll be ok... also perhaps your answer will be the best one here if you do so. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage in PCI terms refers to data being written to disk and generally not to data which is stored in Volatile RAM. The reference to storage for store and forward is to disk and is to allow devices store cardholder validation information pending a device being able to connect or reconnect to a Payment Service Provider or acquirer for the purposes of authenticating the cardholder to allow authorisation of the transaction. In PCI, this data cannot be stored subsequent to the transaction i.e. once its purpose is fulfilled, it must be deleted.

The process you're referring to must include PIN storage in the back end which is permissible for issuers only and that data must be securely stored. You're also describing storing the data in Volatile RAM which is permissible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to violate the requirement you posted and there is no reason to do it. Just generate a token after the pin is verified the first time and the provide the token + OTP to verify second time.

Comment: OP gives a specific reason to do it: `In order to prevent abuse of back-end resources and possible PIN blocking at scale`

Comment: How does storing pin make it different than using a token?

Comment: The issue is that if you only do the OTP after the pin is verified it allows someone to attempt multiple pin verifications without ever doing the OTP.

Comment: How does storing the PIN prevent that? You can just put a cool-down there the same as you could with storing the pin.

Comment: The problem is that the OP doesn't want to verify the PIN at all before the OTP is verified. A token would only work if you verified the PIN before creating the token, otherwise it is meaningless.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald now I think I understand. But this approach could result in SMS spam. Anyone without knowing the correct pin could request the verification SMS. The better approach in this case would be to issue an invalid token for incorrect PIN and pretend to send the SMS, but not do that. It should not leak any information and prevent SMS spam, achieving best of both worlds. Alternatively could send an SMS about wrong PIN attempting login but only the first time (reset after next login).